# Get values from DB field into an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a field in my DB that holds value separated by commas like;

```
$tmp_list = "COB,ISJ,NSJ,"
```

Now when I fetch that the row, I would like to have them in an array. 
I have used `array($tmp_list)` but I get the values in one line only like:

```
[0] => 'COB,ISJ,NSJ,'
```

instead of

```
[0] => 'COB',
[1] => 'ISJ',
[2] => 'NSJ'
```

All help is appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$arr = explode(',', $tmp_list);
```

If you like, remove the trailing comma using [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) first:

```
$arr = explode(',', rtrim($tmp_list, ','));
```

You can also trim each element if there's a chance of getting any unwanted leading/trailing whitespace in one or more elements (as per @machine's suggestion):

```
$arr = array_map('trim', explode(',', rtrim($tmp_list, ',')));
```

Comment: you might also want to run all elements through the trim-function, in case it's saved with spaces in the database: array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $tmp_list ) );